# Where can I find visio shapes for software development?

Tags: visio, shapes, diagrams

Anyone have any ideas on where to get a really nice collection of visio shapes, e.g for the following purposes:

- network diagrams
- shapes to show solution deployments
- any other fancy looking diagrams for software development?

Comment: shapes for what purpose?

Comment: network diagrams, other useful shapes to show solution deployments and other fancy looking diagrams for software development.

Answer (score 3):

[Pavel Hruby](http://phruby.com/) has some nice stencils for UML and SysML on his site. I use the UML stencils all the time, because they are a lot easier to use than the ones provided by visio.

Answer (score 1):

There is a nice bunch of visio shapes for gui mockups [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/MSCRM3/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=188).

Comment: The link seems to be outdated.

Answer (score 1):

(1)
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=6297CF81-C071-4BEA-BD9D-FDE692536E5A&amp;displaylang=f&displaylang=en

The above URL now redirects to:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=25110

The above URLS (at the time of writing) take me to a page titled:

**"Software and Database Shapes for Microsoft Visio"**

Below is another option.  Some are "for pay".

(2)
http://www.visiocafe.com/microsoft.htm